# How to show a default value on a select within a form like {!! Form in Vue and Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a vue.js variable that looks great in echo but I can't set it as the default on a select as I show you:

```
<!-- here it works correctly showing the value that should be the default correctly -->
@{{ $store.state.item.types_id }} 

<!-- here don't working -->
{!! Form::select('types_id', $types, @{{$store.state.item.types_id}}) !!}
```

As you can see, this @{{store.state.item.types_id}} doesn't work and doesn't put the proper value inside the form, what should I do to make it work correctly?
I just want to set this variable @{{store.state.item.types_id}} as the default in select. Some help, please!

Comment: {!! syntax belongs to php, @{{ belongs to javascript. When you enter the page, first php renders, then javacript renders. So php doesnt accept javascript variables. There is 2 way to what you try. Set the selected value after javascript rendered using vue, or  set the selected value in php render time using php variables.

Comment: Thank you so much, then can you show me one example, maybe JS or php, please!